# Custom reduction on GPU vs CPU yield different result

Tags: python, lambda, gpu, numba, reduction

Why am I seeing different result on GPU compare to sequential CPU?

```python
import numpy
from numba import cuda
from functools import reduce

A = (numpy.arange(100, dtype=numpy.float64)) + 1
cuda.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b * 20)(A) 
# result 12952749821.0
reduce(lambda a, b: a + b * 20, A) 
# result 100981.0

import numba
numba.__version__
# '0.34.0+5.g1762237'
```

Similar behavior happens when using Java Stream API to parallelize reduction on CPU:

```java
int n = 10;
float inputArray[] = new float[n];
ArrayList<Float> inputList = new ArrayList<Float>();
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    inputArray[i] = i+1;
    inputList.add(inputArray[i]);
}
Optional<Float> resultStream = inputList.stream().parallel().reduce((x, y) -> x+y*20);
float sequentialResult = array[0];
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
{
    sequentialResult = sequentialResult + array[i] * 20;            
}
System.out.println("Sequential Result "+sequentialResult); 
// Sequential Result 10541.0
System.out.println("Stream Result "+resultStream.get()); 
// Stream Result 1.2466232E8
```

Comment: Just for help with figuring out what might be going on, does this reproduce if your arange is to 3 instead of 10?

Comment: no, with 3 both give the same answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that, as pointed by [Numba's team](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2480), `lambda a, b: a + b * 20` isn't **[associative and commutative](http://developer.amd.com/resources/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/) reduction function** which yield to this unexpected result.